# Can't see "import my LinkedIn profile details" button on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I've read [this meta SE question on importing information from LinkedIn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80759/importing-information-from-the-linkedin-account-to-careers-2-0), and I swear I've seen that import button 2 months ago. It *should* be under "Careers" > "My Profile" > "Import LinkedIn" button.

From the [FAQ](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> **I have a LinkedIn profile. Can it be imported?**
>
> Yes! You can import your LinkedIn profile in just three clicks. Go to your profile and in the right hand column you can choose to “import linkedin”. From there just log into LinkedIn and you’re all set.

Maybe I'm just being blur or dumb today but I cannot for the life of me find that button. I've also disabled Adblock on this site (I remember AdBlock causing issues), and also read that some users see the button after changing from being a passive candidate to an active one, which I've done too.

It does mention that I need to complete other steps to unlock my profile (which requires me giving information I've already posted on LinkedIn). Could that be a reason? If so, I feel that the FAQ should mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's alright, I finally found it.

It's been pushed down the bar that asks you to add more information, hidden right below like so:

[image]

Comment: It is no longer possible: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312851/feature-request-import-cv-from-linkedin

Comment: Welp, that sucks. :/