# Feature Request: Import CV from LinkedIn

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Will be feature **Import CV from [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com)** supported?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with [developer-story]?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We used to have this, but LinkedIn changed their terms of service and we were notified that we had to discontinue the feature.

Comment: To be more clear: when we first created the feature it was definitely within their Terms of Service. They then modified their ToS and notified us that we had to discontinue the feature.

Comment: So the real question is will it be supported again? @DavidFullerton

Comment: @JustDoIt Not unless LinkedIn changes their Terms of Service. They are explicitly aiming at disallowing sites like ours from importing profiles. They perceive it as a competitive threat as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is possible to import from a file, after exported from other sites (eg linkedin)?

Comment: @DavidFullerton If you happen to have a link to a page over at LinkedIn where us users who are now frustrated with their ToS can direct our unhappiness, please just let us know :)  A UserVoice request we can upvote, for example, would be perfect.

Comment: Am equally frustrated about this