# Feature request: upload CV in recognised formats?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I found this well-received POST...

*[Feature Request: Import CV from LinkedIn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312851/feature-request-import-cv-from-linkedin)*

This feature request was declined. However, I was surprised to see no similar request to upload CV in [Microsoft Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) and [ODT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification#File_types) formats.

I would like to make a request for this feature since nearly all job hunting websites allow this - e.g. Reed, Monster to name but 2.

Comment: Are you using [meta-tag:developer-story] or [meta-tag:careers]?

Comment: I am not sure - careers I think - I can edit the CV by clicking the EDIT CV link on the page ... http://stackoverflow.com/users/1205871/danday74 ... this takes me to ... http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit/309983 ... where i can edit the CV but I would like to upload my CV which is in ODT format

Comment: Parsing an arbitrary Word file to find bits of information that can then be pasted into the highly specific format of the Careers CV is not trivial. What Monster seems to be doing is simply allow a plain text import, no?

Comment: Monster supports a lot of approaches. For example, you can enter data about yourself in a form (same as the existing SO approach). Alternatively, you can upload a CV in a recognized format. Employers can then view your CV via a CV preview facility - this previews your ODT / Word CV. (Monster also extracts info from your uploaded CV for its own purposes but I am not suggesting SO incorporate this)